# how to make html table from an array with angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an array like-:

```
aw_score_list = {
    '6':99,'5.5':98,'5':93,'4.5':80,'4':56,'3.5':38,'3':15,'2.5':7,'2':2,'1.5':1,'1':1,
};
```

I want to convert this to html table so it will become like

```
keys     Values
   6         99
 5.5         98
```

... and so on

please advise me how to set a for loop for it

Comment: use ng-repeat . ng-repeat="(key, val) in aw_score_list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [ngRepeat - Iterating over object properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties).

Assuming your array is in scope for the template...

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>keys</th>
    <th>Values</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in aw_score_list">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{val}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it is not working . let me tell you i using your code in my app like 

  <div ng-app="gre_angu_app" class="form-group"  ng-controller="gre_angu_ctrl">
   <!-- angular table code-->..
  </div>

Comment: @vipulsharma as I mentioned in my answer, I assumed you'd have something like `$scope.aw_score_list = {...}` in your controller

Comment: oh how can i get them in desc order ?? :(

Comment: @vipulsharma Get *what* in descending order? The keys or values? See the other answer for a possible solution

Comment: with respect to keys desc order

Answer (score 1):

That is possible, but the order will be messed up, if you want to preserve order, you need something like this:

```
aw_score_list_preserve_order = [    
    {key:'6'   , value:99},
    {key:'5.5' , value:98},
    {key:'5'   , value:93},
    {key:'4.5' , value:80},
    {key:'4'   , value:56},
    {key:'3.5' , value:38},
    {key:'3'   , value:15},
    {key:'2.5' , value:7},
    {key:'2'   , value:2},
    {key:'1.5' , value:1},
    {key:'1'   , value:1},
  ]
```

this is pretty basic ng-repeat iteration, you should probably check out the angular documentation.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cei7pgzGGSmXc55tzR7t)

Comment: If u want it descending ordered, u can simply do: `<div ng-repeat="item in aw_score_list_preserve_order | orderBy:key:true">...</div>`, if you want ascending order, take out the `:true` part, check documentation for orderBy.

Comment: Check the plunker again, I have renew my code. You probably need your keys to be number not string to get the result you want.

Comment: i can't change array sturcture .. i m following the @phil way . which is working  too the only issue remain for set order by desc w.r.t. keys

Comment: You can change the array structure in your code, like so [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cei7pgzGGSmXc55tzR7t)